# How to execute a specific SQL-Query on a jButton with java in swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible to execute a SQL query directly when clicking on a jButton?

For example, in a jDialog I have a textfield for the Username and a savebutton.

jButton Action:

```
@Action
public void saveNewUser() {
  Statement s = con.createStatement();
  s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO User (username) " + " VALUES ('"+ username + "')")
}
```

So I would need to get the String from the Username textfield, but how?

Comment: Yes anything is possible. Read up on the swing tutorials to get a grasp of the framework. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 4):

You should review the Swing API. The textfield would be a JTextField. Here is a link to the Java JDK API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ and Here is one directly to JTextField: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

Here is some very simplified code that does what you want (I am ignoring layout, i18n, and other various improvements):

```
JTextField usernameTextField = new JTextField("Username:");
JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");

saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener())
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    String username = usernameTextField.getText();
    //Put validation code here if you want

    //Then put your SQL insert statement code here
  }
});

//Generally you will be adding them to a JPanel, but can be a JFrame for simple cases
panel.add(usernameTextField);
panel.add(saveButton);

...
```